# JSFiddle script not working locally

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I'm sure this is something silly I'm missing but after searching here and on jsfiddle I just haven't been able to figure out how to get a working script from jsfiddle to work on my local server. I have the javascript, loaded the jquery and the html but it doesn't work. Is there something else I need to do to get a jsfiddle script to work on the server?

This is my test page: 
    http://waterwalkmedia.com/link-test.html

Okay, trying again.  On jsfiddle there is the following code:

This is the HTML code:

```
    <div id="stateSelection">Jump to State: <a id="Conn" class="state-link"    data-region-type="4" data-region-code="09" href="#">Connecticut</a> | <a id="Maine" class="state-link" data-region-type="4" data-region-code="23" href="#">Maine</a> | <a id="Mass" class="state-link" data-region-type="4" data-region-code="25" href="#">Massachusetts</a> | <a id="Rh" class="state-link" data-region-type="4" data-region-code="44" href="#">Rhode Island</a> 
</div> <span class="lbl">Display by: </span>
 <a id="ctyRegion" class="map-type-link" region_type="1" href="javascript://">County</a> | <a id="msaRegion" class="map-type-link" region_type="2" href="javascript://">Metro-Area</a> 
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
    $('#msaRegion').click(function () {
    $(".state-link").addClass('disableClass');
});
$('#ctyRegion').click(function () {
    $(".state-link").removeClass('disableClass');
});
```

This is the CSS:

```
    a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: #c7d1d6;
}
.disableClass {
    pointer-events:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity: 0.4;
    cursor:default;
}
.enableClass {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events:all;
    cursor:default;
}
```

The link to the actual working jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/8u4jw72h/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: The jsfiddle link doesn't work.

Comment: Now the link to the working example just goes to the stackoverflow.com home page.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Why can't I just put the jsfiddle link in? I keep getting an error telling me I have to paste the jsfiddle code with 4 spaces in front yet I don't see all the other posts doing that

Comment: If it tells you that you have to do it that way, do it that way.  If other posts did so before that policy was added they aren't going to be retroactively punished or anything

Comment: We don't want people just posting links to jsfiddle. You're supposed to post the actual code, and use the jsfiddle link as extra supporting documentation.

Comment: As you can tell it's my first time here.  The indent 4 wasn't working so I was giving up adding code but the control - k finally worked.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it must be something simple I was missing. That helped.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside `$(document).ready()` so that it will run after the DOM is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#msaRegion').click(function () {
        $(".state-link").addClass('disableClass');
    });
    $('#ctyRegion').click(function () {
        $(".state-link").removeClass('disableClass');
    });
});
```

It works in jsfiddle because you used the default `onLoad` option.